# Discord bot message is not embedded

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

With following code:

```
        message.reply('some reply', { embed: {
            color: 3447003,
            description: "A very simple Embed!"
          }
        });
    }
```

my bot response will look like a normal message. I looked up several tutorials on this topic. None could me help. I also tried `message.send` or `message.channel.send`. Same/similar results.
I aim to have something like shown here:
https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#embed-preview

Comment: Are you using Discord V13?

Comment: I use 13.1.0. Could it be disabled by my server settings?

Comment: Sorry I meant the version of **Discord.js** and not Discord itself haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since **Discord.js V13** you have to pass embeds to the `.send()`/ `.reply()`, etc. function(s) like this:

```js
const embed = {
   color: 3447003,
   description: "A very simple Embed!"
}

message.reply({ content: "Your content", embeds: [embed] })

// Or ...

message.channel.send({ content: "Your content", embeds: [embed] })
```

Comment: you mean `message.channel.send`?

Comment: Oh oops, yeah.. thanks

Comment: Works with `message.channel.send`. Finally! Thanks guys.

Answer (score 3):

[`Message.reply`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=reply), [`TextChannel.send`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send), and [`Message.edit`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=edit) now only take one argument. Changing it to this will work:

```js
message.reply({
  content: 'some reply', 
  embeds: [{
    color: 3447003,
    description: "A very simple Embed!"
  }]
});
```

Comment: Just tested it, parameter `embed` doesn't seems to be working. If you do `embeds` (Array) it could work.

Comment: yes my bad, I didn't notice it, I just copy-pasted

Comment: No problem, cheers! ^^.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I still get `DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message`

Comment: This works fine, just be a problem with your code

Comment: If this helped, you can mark it as correct with the checkmark!

Comment: Only works using `message.channel.send` so hesitating to add checkmark

Comment: I still added the concept, and it works for me

Comment: my exec command runs javascript code from discord - [here is the test](https://imgur.com/a/7R8ZKjC)